# Notification Window position

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have created a notification window in a Silverlight 4 application. Problem is the notification window is located in bottom right corner with a margin of about 50px.

Is it possible to set the position of the notification window explicit?

Comment: Its possible to see a screenshot from a notification window in this blog post from tim heuer: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/22/silverlight-4-notification-window-queue-sample.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice wouldn't it.  But alas no, there is currently no way to control the screen position of the toast.  I'm not sure whether this is an oversight, technically difficult or a "stop bad people doing bad things" type of issue.